Copying a column to a new sheet in Excel
I have a spreadsheet, and I have some code that isn't working.
I need to copy over rows of data to another sheet based on if column K is populated (with a date).
The code is stopping and I don't know why (I'm not very good).
I can attach the sheet - the code is:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim wsPaid      As Worksheet: Set wsPaid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Paid")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("K")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In Target
            
            If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
                Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.Range("A:M"))
                lastRow = wsPaid.Cells(wsPaid.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                rng.Copy wsPaid.Range("A" & lastRow)
                wsPaid.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
                rng.Delete
            End If

        Next cell

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I tried the code, but it stops at
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("K")) Is Nothing Then
so I don't get far. Column K is the paid column in the sample and the first entry (highlighted) is an example of what I want to go to a second sheet.
I want it to run each time it is opened, and for new entries then to go to the bottom of the second sheet. The sheets are unpaid and paid respectively.
Any help would be appreciated on what I've done wrong.


Stops because 1. Me is the name of the workbook, and you need the name of the sheet where column K is tested. 2. Target must be defined somehow.

It seems like the code is either from the Worksheet_Change or  Worksheet_SelectionChange event. In these events, argument Target refers to the range that was changed or selected. However, in Workbook_Open, Target doesn't have any meaning. So you'll need to define it as a variable and assign a range object to it using the Set clause before using it.

As @taller commented this is the adapted code in the open event of the Workbook. Me were changed to the corresponding sheetnames.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim wsPaid As Worksheet: Set wsPaid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Paid")
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet: Set wsLookup = Worksheets("Unpaid") 'change to the actual name of  the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In wsLookup.Columns("K").Cells
            
            If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
                Set rng = Intersect(cell.EntireRow, wsLookup.Columns("A:M"))
                lastRow = wsPaid.Cells(wsPaid.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                rng.Copy wsPaid.Range("A" & lastRow)
                wsPaid.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
                rng.Delete
            End If

        Next cell

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Note: To speed up the process you can limit the Columns("K") range for the actual range of the column e.g. similar to lastrow and wsPaid.Range("A" & lastRow) but now for Column K.
